# Paginating Tags in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, tags

I'm using Kaminari to paginate my posts page. A post has many tags and each tag links to a "Show" page that displays all posts with that tag. I'm trying to paginate this tags page but it never quite works.

tags/show

```
<div class="post-index">
    <h1><%= @tag.name %></h1>
    <ul>
      <% @tag.posts.each do |post| %>
        <li>
            <div class="post">
                <div class="featured-image">
                    <%= link_to image_tag(post.featured_image.url(:featured)), post_path(post) %>
                </div>

                <div class="info">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h2><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="excerpt">
                        <p><%= truncate(strip_tags(post.body), length: 360) %></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <%= paginate @tags %>
</div>
```

tag.rb

```
lass Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :posts, through: :taggings

    paginates_per 2
end
```

tags_controller.rb

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
    def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id]).page(params[:page])
    end
end
```

I've tried all I can think of. The examples Kaminari uses are

```
tag = Tag.order(:name).page(params[:page])
```

but this doesn't work and returns a no method "posts" error. I tried paginating the posts model instead but that doesn't work.

If I remove any pagination reference, it displays all the posts correctly on the tag page.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about what do you want to paginate? Tags or posts? In your code, you want to paginate "@tags", but you never define "@tags".

```
@tag = Tag.find(params[:id]) 
@posts = @tag.posts.page(params[:page])
```

Comment: Ahh yeah it was just like this after I had messed around trying a lot of things. Either way, `@tag` or `@tags` nothing changes. I want to paginate posts, in the tags controller/view. Posts belong to tags, so I figured I'd need to paginate that.

P.S I know nothing, real beginner.

Comment: You can use "@tag = Tag.find(params[:id])" to get current tag. And then "@tag.posts" can get all posts belong this tag.

Comment: Yes, that's how it is now. My problem is with paginating the posts now.

Comment: What is your problem now?

Comment: Did you change your answer? I used that second line (didn't see it before) and it works now. Thank you very much!